# Run a script in Python several times and save the output

Tags: python

I have a script called `script.py` in python which chooses some random values from some distributions with given mean and standard deviation and then do some calculations with these values. I'm doing this for seven different distributions in a loop of 2000 time steps. After some extra calculations, `script.py` returns a vector as a final output. What I want to do is run this script 100 times simultaneously (I don't want the results of one run affect the results of others) and I want to know this output vector for each of the 100 runs in order to find an average at the end. A good way would be to save each vector as a column in a matrix with 100 columns.

I have tried subproccess but I'm having trouble finding a way to save the output of each run. Any help would be much appreciated.

A part of my code includes the following:

```
for k in range(N2):     
     for i in range(7):
        sample2 = np.random.normal(prior[i,0],prior[i,1],1)
        y[i] = sample2[0]
     index, value = max(enumerate(y), key=operator.itemgetter(1)) 
     indices[k] = index
     #trials[k,index] = trials[k-1,index]+1

     realdata = np.random.normal(parameters[index,0],parameters[index,1],1)                        

     ytrue[k] = realdata[0]
     prior[index,0] = (prior[index,0]/prior[index,1]**2+ytrue[k]/variance)/(1./prior[index,1]**2+1./variance)
     prior[index,1] = math.sqrt(1./(1./prior[index,1]**2+1./variance))
     meanforoptions[k,:] = prior[:,0]
     regret = parameters[1,0]-ytrue[k]
     cumulativeregret[k] = cumulativeregret[k-1]+regret
```

Basically I want to calculate cumulativeregret 100 times and then calculate the average. Running the script only one time doesn't give me sufficient results because there is a lot of randomness in the proccess. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the code you're using to save the outputs? Also there might be other mistakes that prevent your code from running correctly. Without code nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: You probably need to start by turning your script into a function.

Comment: Without a [mcve] I'm afraid it will be nearly impossible to help you. If your code is very long and complicated/proprietary you don't need to provide the whole thing, just the gist - i.e. the parts that involve what you're trying with subprocess and actually saving output. You could just return a random/constant vector, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You could run it 100 time using **parallel** - if you have a multi core server with multi CPU's it will genuinely run them all in parallel.

Off the top of my head something like this should work.

```
 parallel -j 100 python script.py > script.out
```